# Laravel : Join 4th table in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i have 3 tables as below

1. Packages
2. Shops
3. shop_packages

I am fetching data from these tables using many to many relationship as below

**Package Model :**

```
 public  function  shops():BelongsToMany{
        return $this->belongsToMany(Shop::class,'shop_packages','package_id','shop_id');
    }
```

**Shop Model**

```
 public  function  packages(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class,'shop_packages','shop_id','package_id');
  }
```

this relation works fine with below code :

```
 Package::with('shops')->where('package_id',$request['package_id'])->first();
```

Now the problem is that i have images against each shop which are saved in a separate  table `attachments` , in the shop list I get using above query how can i get at-least one image against each shop ? can someone please guide me

Comment: what have you tried ? how is the attachments linked to the shops ? What is the logic behind choosing one image from the list of images linked to the shop ?

Comment: attachment has  the fields  ( attachment_id, type (shop in this case) , ref_id (shop id in this case ), name (image name )

Comment: i was able to get it using joins but have no idea how it works with joins

Comment: use a polymorphic relation then, and use the relation as any other one. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: should i completely consider redoing the relationships for getting shops and packages ? using polymorphic

Comment: no you need to defined a relation between shop and attachement called images and use it in your query like `->with('shops.images')` and be done

Comment: public function attachment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Attachment::class, 'ref_id', 'shop_id');
    }  had this on in my attachment but did not know about  shop.attachment